# how to translate website to another language angular

Tags: angular, localization

I have a ready site in Russian, it needs to be translated into another language using angular localization.  Please advise where I can watch or read about it.

Comment: Maybe you want to try this one: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core

Comment: if you want to create two differents app (one is, e.g. www.mysite.com and the other www.mysite.com/en-BG) the aproach is the i18n in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/i18n-overview), if you want switch the language at run time you can use [transloco](https://ngneat.github.io/transloco/) or ngx-translate

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend to use a [Transloco](https://ngneat.github.io/transloco/). One of the best internationalization library for Angular. Atleast for me. You can watch guides on yt or read documentation and i think atleast in my opinions that this is the easyest way to translate your web.